# Lazy loading have error using ngxBoostrap modal

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, ngx-bootstrap-modal

I have main `AppRoutingModule` class where I set my routes and add in my `appModule`:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'shopCart', component: ShopCartComponent },
  { path: 'administration', loadChildren: './admin/admin.module#AdminModule' },
  { path: 'productsList', loadChildren: './products/products.module#ProductsModule' },
  { path: 'not-found', component: PageNotFoundComponent, data: { message: 'Page not found!' } },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/not-found' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })

  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

In `appModule`I am add in imports module

```
ModalModule.forRoot(),
NgbModule.forRoot(),
```

And in `providers` I am add `NgbActiveModal`.
I want to lazy load `admin.module` and in this module I have `modal`.

My admin.module is :

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    AdminRoutingModule,
    NgbModule,
    AlertModule.forRoot()

  ],
  declarations: [
    AdminComponent,
    CategoryComponent,
    ProductModal

  ]
  , entryComponents: [
    CategoryComponent,
    ProductModal
  ]

})
export class AdminModule { }
```

All work good and that I click on the my modal I click on the modal, I have error :

```
ERROR Error: No component factory found for CategoryComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
```

I followed this link [link](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap#installation)

I want to mention, everything was working good before Lazy loading.

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: You can see on the GitHub `https://github.com/milos2611/shop`.

Answer (score 3):

You have to move your `dynamic components` to a higher level so that angular can find them if you want create them without using `ng-templates`

So in your case you add this to your `app.module.ts`

```
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        // Other imports....

      ],
      entryComponents: [
        CategoryComponent,
        ProductModal
      ],
      providers: [
           // other providers...
        ],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent],


    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Remove this from `admin.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // Other Imports....    
  ],
  declarations: [
    AdminComponent,
    // CategoryComponent, -> Removed
    // ProductModal -> Removed

  ]
  , entryComponents: [
    // CategoryComponent, -> Removed
    // ProductModal -> Removed
  ]

})
export class AdminModule { }
```

This should make your application generate Modals.

You can read more about `entryComponents` [here](https://angular.io/guide/entry-components)

**Another Simpler Solution**

Move the `Modal.forRoot()` method to the LazyLoaded Module `admin.module.ts`

so your `admin.module.ts` becomes

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // Add this, Remove for `app.module.ts`
    ModalModule.forRoot(),

  ],
  declarations: [
    AdminComponent,
    CategoryComponent,
    ProductModal

  ]
  , entryComponents: [
    CategoryComponent,
    ProductModal
  ]

})
export class AdminModule { }
```

Comment: If this helped please accept the answer, this will help others when they see this :)

Comment: This works, but it is not really the correct answer. The problem with this is it breaks the angular module flow. If i did this i would end up having 50 components in my main module.

Comment: @SamuelThompson you should use dynamic module loading. I think the component forces you to declare components in the module where you are doing `forRoot()` (I may be wrong, check the documentation for this).

Comment: You are correct, and that is the only way of doing it... but at the same time, it is a really bad way of doing it. Right now ngx-bootstrap is broken in that sense. There is no real good solution to the problem.